# Problem with SP in C#: expects the parameter '@Image', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server

I ran into a problem for which I couldn't find a solution in existing similarly asked questions. The problem is that I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_EditCustomer @ID int, @Name NVarchar(100), @Email Nvarchar(200), @Contact bigint, 
@Address NVarchar(350), @About NVarChar(350), @Image image = null
AS
if(@Image is null)
Begin
UPDATE clientTable
SET ClientName = @Name, Contact= @Contact, Address = @Address, About = @About, Email = @Email
                 WHERE ClientID = @ID;
End
Else
Begin
UPDATE clientTable
SET ClientName = @Name, Contact= @Contact, Address = @Address, About = @About, Email = @Email,
                 Photo = @Image
                 WHERE ClientID = @ID;
End
```

I have set the **@image** parameter to be **null** as default but whenever I connect to SQL Server with the following code in C# winforms:

```
// Inserting image into DB
byte[] img = null;
if (imgLoc != null && imgLoc != "")
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
}
else
{
    img = null;
}

    //Connecting to Database
    cmd = conString.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Exec SP_EditCustomer @ID, @Name, @Email, @Contact, @Address, @About, @Image";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtEditByID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtFullName.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txtContact.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 350).Value = txtAddress.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@About", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 350).Value = txtAbout.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;

    conString.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conString.Close();
```

I get this error:

> The parameterized query '(@ID int,@Name nvarchar(100),@Email nvarchar(200),@Contact bigin' expects the parameter '@Image', which was not supplied.

Although if no new image is selected then the existing image shouldn't change (and for this purpose I have passed null but still I get the error above).

Comment: You need to set your parameter to `DBNull.Value` to use a database null, which is different to a C# null. And a quick google returns me lots of results for that error.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you solved it with DBNull.Value. I have used DBNull.Value incorrectly while trying the solutions.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for suggesting that, I will update the names of my SPs.

Comment: You should not use `exec SPName @a, @b` but rather set the command text to `SPName` (only) and then `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Then, you could just not set the Image parameter at all if it's null (also I *think* that using `null` works in that case). Don't call `ToString` on the `Text` properties--they are already strings! Since dealing with user input you should use `int.TryParse` and `long.TryParse` for the ID and Contact parameters (unless those are uneditable text boxes in which case `Parse` should be fine) - - Convert has weird behavior for bad input

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DaleK for suggesting the DBNull.Value.

I have solved it with his suggestion by adding the following lines:

```
 if(img!=null)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
 else
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = DBNull.Value;
```